# A question about Answer Time

Tags: discussion, support, answers, information-display

In my opinion, first given best answer should take up vote. In an hour, we can see which one is given first like (10 min ago, 15 min ago, etc.) But after an hour, these times looks like 1h ago on every answer given in 1h ago. So, Im confusing which one is given first. Some users can make copy/paste or gives similar answers. Is it possible to add minute detail in answers? For example, "answered 1h 22m ago", "answered 1h 36m ago". So I can see that which answer is best and given early :)

Is it possible on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Upvotes are free.  Is it really necessary or useful to split hairs about which one of two more-or-less equivalent answers was posted first?

Answer (score 2):

You can hover over the time to see the actual timestamp (to the second) of the answer.  It's what I use as a tiebreaker when things are too close to call like that :)

Comment: actually I can use oldest tab to see it. I just want to know, isnt is better to put minute detail in answers?

Comment: Once answers are more than an hour old I don't know that the exact "who is first" typically matters since usually one answer has better content by that point.  I typically use the hover timestamp for when there's a short and sweet answer and it's within the first few minutes of the answer being posted.